# How are monosaccharides and amino acids absorbed in jejunum?

Tags: digestion

> Duodenum receives bile from liver and Pancreatic juice from pancreas. Intestinal glands secrete Intestinal juice which acts at the **ileum**. Most of the absorption of food materials takes place in the **jejunum**, except for iron(duodenum) Vit $B_{12}$ and bile salts(terminal ileum).

I am learnt in high school text books that the succus entericus(intestinal juice) helps convert disaccharides to monosaccharides, dipeptides to amino acids and emulsified fat into fatty acids and glycerol. Then that implies that carbohydrates(monosaccharides) and proteins(amino acids) can**not** be absorbed in the **jejunum** since they are not yet in the absorbable state(due to absence of succus entericus in jejunum). Then why only absorption of Vit $B_{12}$ and bile salts take place in ileum and not end products of digestion? How can they be absorbed in jejunum?